# How to attach Jar in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Now days I am getting a problem in attaching JAR files in Blackberry.....
I am using Eclipse 3.5 and I am using Facebook Jar SDK , in my Application.

I am doing the following things for attach the Jar in my Application

1. Copy the Jar in my Application Resources
2. Right Click on MyProject "Properties" , then a window appear I select "Java Buid Path" and select "Libraries"  and select "Add JAR" option ...and last I give the path of Jar wher I put it.
3. And Go to "Order and Export"  and select the Added Jar (Check Mark ), then press Ok

Application compiles fine , but when I click on Application Icon it gives me Message `Verification code error in particular Module`

Why this Error come .. please explain me 
Thanks

Comment: try another way.. create a library project and add the jar file to that and then connect that jar file to your project

Comment: what is the process to create library project & why above method not working ? @ArunKumarMunusamy

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261164/913422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step you are missing is called "preverifying" the jar file.

There is a very good answer on how to run `preverify.exe` at this link: [Blackberry 5.0 - Add reference to a Java Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9111074/383414).

Other related posts are:

- [Blackberry: Verificattion error when using Library project as External Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902639/blackberry-verificattion-error-when-using-library-project-as-external-jar)
- http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/quot-Project-0-has-to-have-a-jad-file-file-if-it-exports-a/ta-p/502501
- http://ahmadferdous.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-import-kxml-jar-file-to-your.html