# How to add library project with the current development project in blackberry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to blackberry, currently I'm developing a project, in that project I need to add a jar(Ksoap) file. For this I created a project and I added the jar file which I required the added it on build path. Finally I try to set blackberry project dependencies with the development project, I could not able to get option to select library project. I refer http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/155972-blackberry-ksoap2-tutorial.html this site.

Im using eclipse indigo 3.7 version.

Can anyone help from me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My recipe:

1. Manually preverify your jar with the `preverify` tool included in the JDE (the path is "C:\Program files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE x.x.x\bin", where the x's are version numbers).
2. Pick the preverivied jar from the "bin\output" directory.
3. Copy the file and paste in your eclipse package explorer, at the root of the workspace, or (if you are using old plugin) inside the `src` folder.
4. Java Build Path -> libraries tab -> add jar.
5. Enjoy, but...

This will work for a given project. If you try to do the same in another project, you'll get a RuntimeException because there are classes with the same name (the package names collide). You can refactor the packages in jar for each project, or add the jar to a library project instead of the main project, so that other projects can use it.

Comment: Hi Minster Smith, Thanks for your reply. I'll try this now