# how to use external jar file in blackberry eclipse plugin

Tags: blackberry

I have a jar file which contains .cod,.cso and .csl files.I need to use the jar file in my blackberry project.I added the jar file to build path of my main project.It was giving the error "Cannot start project has verification errors". I preverified the jar file and added to the build path and exported the jar file(Right click on project -> Libraries ->Order and Export).When I export the jar file the project is not compiling.Can anyone suggest me to add the external jar file to my project.

regards

Comment: There are dozens similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260728/how-to-add-library-project-with-the-current-development-project-in-blackberry/9261164#9261164 for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external Jar file ->and check the jar file you have added in the Order and Export Tab.** And press ok .

Or you can also use a library to add the jar to your project do it like this way.

- First make a folder lib in your project.
- Right-click your project > Properties
- Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs… > Choose the JAR files in the “lib” folder
- Java Build Path > Order and Export > Check the JAR files. and then ok. may be this will help you

Comment: that means you have not preverified the jar file correctly. Other wise it should work